# Web and CLI mysql won't connect at the same time

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I have setup my Laravel application using Laravel Sail (Docker based). Everything's working fine except the MySQL. MySQL server is behaving differently for web (`local.mysite.com:8080`) and for CLI (ex: `php artisan migrate`).

**Configruation (1)**

If I use the following configuration  in my `.env` file,

```
...
APP_DOMAIN=local.mysite.com
...
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307
```

the web works, not the CLI. When I run `php artisan migrate` command I get `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`

**Configuration (2)**

And if I use the following configuration,

```
...
APP_DOMAIN=local.mysite.com
...
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=local.mysite.com 
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307
```

The CLI works fine, not the web. I get a `Connection Refured` error by MySQL on web.

I've been banging my head with different tries, no luck...

What am I doing wrong?

---

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` for reference (`phpmyadmin` is working real good btw):

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '8081:80'
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        networks:
            - sail

    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        extra_hosts:
            - '${APP_DOMAIN}:127.0.0.1'
        hostname: '${APP_DOMAIN}'
        domainname: '${APP_DOMAIN}'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake.

I should be using `sail artisan migrate` instead of `php artisan migrate` as clearly explained in the official [Laravel Sail documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#executing-sail-commands).

The correct configuration therefore is:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307
```